# ODOO installation, unmet dependencies

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to install ODOO on my VPS,

Following the official documentation on https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html, when i run

```
apt-get update && apt-get install odoo
```

I get the following message :

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 odoo : Depends: python3-gevent but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-passlib but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-pyldap but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-qrcode but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-suds but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-usb but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-vobject but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have both python 2.7.9 and python 3.4.2 installed. I'm running Debian 8.8.
Same thing happens with only python 2.7.9 installed.

Running

`apt-get install python-dev`

or

```
apt-get install python3-dev
```

Didn't help solving the issue.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try with adding missing libraries and re-run it ..

Comment: I'had the same prooblem, and i installed all libraries manually

Comment: `apt-get install python-passlib` or `pip install passlib` ...

Comment: Or you can install automatically using pycharm

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The documentation here ( https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/install.html#setup-install-packaged) does not work for ubuntu 14. I upgraded to ubuntu 16 and my problem was fixed.

Comment: You are using Odoo 11, which doesn't work for the author's system (Debian 8), but Odoo 10 is ok on Jessie.